# Swift, Cocoa - how to update view properties when using an NSGraphicsContext?

Tags: swift, cocoa

If I call self.layer? in a draw() method to control the content of an NSView, the view's properties can be updated by the view controller. However, if I create a graphics context for drawing into, this relationship breaks and the view controller no longer updates the view's properties. Why?

In the simple example I provide, if you comment out the guard statement in TestView and call drawBackgroundWithoutContext(), the view is given a background colour when viewDidLoad() is called, and the colour is updated when the mouseDown event occurs.

As soon as a context is declared this breaks, even if you are still calling drawBackgroundWithoutContext().

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    var newR: CGFloat?
    var newG: CGFloat?
    var newB: CGFloat?
    
    var tview = TestView(frame: NSRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tview.r = 1.0
        tview.g = 0.5
        tview.b = 0.8
        self.view.addSubview(tview)
    }
    
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        newR = 0.1
        newG = 0.9
        newB = 0.0
        tview.r = newR
        tview.g = newG
        tview.b = newB
        tview.draw(NSRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
//      tview.setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
    }
}


    class TestView: NSView {
        
        var r: CGFloat?
        var g: CGFloat?
        var b: CGFloat?
        
        override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
            super.draw(dirtyRect)
            
            guard  let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else {
                return
            }
            
    //      drawBackgroundWithoutContext(red: r, green: g, blue: b)
            
            drawBackgroundWithContext(context: context, red: r, green: g, blue: b)
            
        }
    
        func drawBackgroundWithoutContext(red: CGFloat?, green: CGFloat?, blue: CGFloat?) {
            self.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor(red: red ?? 0.0, green: green ?? 0.0, blue: blue ?? 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        
        func drawBackgroundWithContext(context: CGContext, red: CGFloat?, green: CGFloat?, blue: CGFloat?) {
            context.setFillColor(CGColor(red: red ?? 0.0, green: green ?? 0.0, blue: blue ?? 0.0, alpha: 1.0))
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
        }
    
    }
```

I read that you should not actually call .draw() in the view controller and the correct method is setNeedsDisplay(), however this had no affect. I have left this call as a comment in the code so you can see what I tried.

Comment: 1. You don't call draw yourself. 2. setFillColor doesn't draw anything by itself.

Comment: Why do you set `self.layer?.backgroundColor` in `draw`? Draw should draw, nothing else. Set `self.layer?.backgroundColor` when `r`, `g` or `b` changes or add a `setLayerColor` function. The layer will redraw automatically.

Comment: @Willeke I am just using background colour as the simplest example I could think of to illustrate the question - the question is really about how to update variables that are used as the basis of drawing into a graphics context

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks yes I have read this but in the case of calling drawBackgroundWithoutContext() in the example, calling tview.draw() in the view controller does gives the behaviour I expect - if I remove it the view is not redrawn - again I read that the correct approach is .setNeedsDisplay() but this didn't do anything

Comment: Add methods to change the variables and call `setNeedsDisplay` if needed in these methods. Let the view decide when display is needed.

Comment: I tried your code and now you've added `context.fill`, `tview.draw` is not needed.